# bash history list view like powershell?

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, shell, psreadline

With PSReadLine 2.2.0 beta4

Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History

Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView

powershell can show history like this:

[image]

Does Bash or any other Linux shell have this feature?

Comment: Powershell is a linux shell. If it has the features you need, what is the reason for needing another?

Comment: you got me. but what I need is Bash with this feature. powershell is good, but it's very windows-like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `history` command to see your previous commands.
If you want to filter then you can use the `grep` command, for example

```
history | grep git
```

you will get for example :

```html
  207  git push origin init-repo
  226  git status
  227  git add war/src/main/java/com/xxx/Application.java
  228  git status
  229  git fetch
  230  git checkout init-repo
  231  git stash
  232  git stash pop
  233  git add pom.xml
  234  git status
  235  git add *
  236  git add all
  237  git add-all
  238  git --help
  239  git add --all
  240  git stash
  241  git stash pop
  242  git add --all
  243  git pull
  502  history | grep git
[admin@host]$
```

Comment: How would one use this in such a way that it is able to "run as you type" and provide a selectable list like shown in the screenshot?